# Legitimacy of Regressing Actual Values on Predicted Values for Better Residual Sum of Squares?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, linear

A coworker of mine recently performed an analysis where after training a simple linear model, he regressed the actual Y values against his model's predicted Y values, and applied this regression's slope and intercept back to the original predictions to get better point-to-point agreement (residual sum of squares) while maintaining the same $R^2$.

I'm not as versed in statistics as he, but I've never heard of such a technique before, and can't find any information online supporting the legitimacy of it. It seems a bit like cheating since he's using the true values post-modeling to forcibly get better point-to-point agreement, but he justifies it by saying the model's ability to predict variance ($R^2$) remains the same, he's just adjusting for the model underestimating the point values.

Is this approach valid?

The following is a toy example of such a calculation:

```
Y_Actual    Y_Predicted 
0.2         0.1         
0.4         0.2         
0.7         0.3 

RSquare:    0.987   
RSS:        0.210
```

Regress Y_Actual on Y_Predicted:

```
Slope:  0.395   
Intercept:  0.029
```

Apply regression for new Y'_Predicted via:
Y'_Predicted = (Y_Predicted - intercept)/slope

```
Y_Actual    Y_Predicted Y'_Predicted
0.2         0.1         0.18
0.4         0.2         0.43
0.7         0.3         0.69

RSquare:    0.987       0.987
RSS:        0.210       0.002
```

As we can see, Y'_Predicted has the same $R^2$ as Y_Predicted, but much better Residual Sum of Squares:

[image: The default model (blue line) has good R^2 but poor point-to-point fit, while applying the regression of actuals to predicted (red line) results in both good point-to-point agreement and R^2]

Answer (score 1):

I believe your colleague made a mistake in claiming that the $R^2$ stays the same.

This is because $R^2$ is defined as:

> $R^2 = 1- {(SS_{res})\over(SS_{tot})}$

The reason they have to be different is because both 1 and $SS_{tot}$ are fixed by the data set. The only thing that changes between the two models is $SS_{res}$. So this seems to suggest there is an issue with your colleagues model or model fit.

If we just plug the two into each other what we get is:

> $Y = \alpha*x + \beta$

Then based on this Y he performed the following regression:

> $Y_2 = \alpha_2*Y + \beta_2$

So if we plug this all into one equation we get:

> $Y_2 = \alpha_2*(\alpha*x + \beta) + \beta_2$

We can simplify this a little bit to show the issue:

> $Y_2 = \alpha_2*\alpha*x + \alpha*\beta + \beta_2$

This is of course just the equation for a line with:

> $slope = \alpha_2*\alpha$

and

> $intercept = \alpha*\beta + \beta_2$

So if your colleague's first model had been fit correctly no improvement should be possible by regressing the predictions on the actual values because a linear model fitting is already doing that.

So I suspect he made a mistake in fitting his data/setting up his model.

Now as to why the $R^2$ can appear to stay unchanged is because there are multiple definitions of $R^2$ and they are only sometimes the same. The definition that I quoted above is useful for the regression context. But it should be identical to simply squaring the correlation coefficient. However, this only holds for a successful least squares fit. So if there is a mistake/issue the two will not be equal. However, it's not clear without knowing which software was use which approach to calculate the $R^2$ was used so the program may just be showing the square of the correlation coefficient.

Comment: Hey Patrick, thanks for taking time to write up this answer. The $R^2$ being used is the square of Pearson's correlation coefficient, which is the same formula you'd find in Excel, Google Sheets, etc. If you plug in the example numbers I provided in the question into those programs, you'll see that both Y_Predicted and Y'_Predicted yield the same $R^2$ in relation to Y_Actual. This is valid for least squares multiple regression, but it sounds like after my coworker's adjustment, his model no longer fulfills the conditions to use this version of $R^2$? So it's an issue of misspecification?

Comment: Misspecification is usually used to to refer to the fact that the model is not accurately describing reality (i.e., the data). In this case though I believe the problem is that there is an actual error in the calculations your coworker performed. Basically if fit correctly regressing the predictions on the actual cannot lead to improvement (independently of how you specified the original model). So the issue is two fold: A) your coworker made an error in their calculation/fitting and B) the results are presented with the wrong definition of $R^2$.

Comment: The Pearson's correlation coefficient should not be used to evaluate the fit of a linear model but the definition that I mentioned should be. For simple linear models the two should be equivalent but only if the model fit is correct. So it makes sense that the $R^2$ doesn't change because the $R^2$ is not, in this case, related to the model that your coworker fit.